# SQL Server & .net support calling a stored procedure with param's values wihout providing param's names?

Tags: .net, sql-server

Assume that I have a store procedure in SQL Server with a name sp_GetData1 with params:

```
@Input1 int
@Input2 string
```

THis stored procedure will return a datatable. To get datatable from this stored procedure, I use ADO.NET. To execute this stored procedure, we **must provide param'name, param's sqldatatype, & param' value**.

I have a question: **We can execute this stored procedure (using ADO.NET) without providing param's name & param's sqldatatype? That mean, I only need providing values of parameters in order.**

Thanks.

Comment: what problem are you trying to solve here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One way to safely execute a stored procedure without directly specifying the names,  direction and type of parameters is to use [SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx).

This will retrieve the parameters from the server amd create the SQLParameter collection for you. You still need to populate the values on the  parameter collection on the command.

```
...I'm assuming  a variable cmd with the command string and connection property set
SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
cmd.Parameters[0].Value = input1;
cmd.Parameters[1].Value = input2;
```

There is a performance penalty for going to the server but at least you don't have to worry about sql injection

The old SQLHelper did this and cached the parameters so it only did it once. Enterprise Library will do the same. Full ORMs also will do similar things for you.

Answer (score 0):

**You can always use the comandText property of command object and execute the SP in the  following way:**

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("My connection string value here");
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
command.CommandText = string.Format("exec storedProcedureName {0},{1}", 1, 2);
SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
adapter.Fill(ds);
```

Comment: lets just hope that @Input2 isn't `; Drop Database master;` also it wouldn't work even for good data since @input2 would need to be delimited with single quotes