# C# SQL execute stored procudere regardless of passed parameter name

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, parameters

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Server & .net support calling a stored procedure with param's values wihout providing param's names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463010/sql-server-net-support-calling-a-stored-procedure-with-params-values-wihout)

I want to call a command.ExecuteReader() of type Stored Procedure, however I do not want the parameter names that I pass to be identical to the ones in the SP. Below is a sample of what I'm trying to do

SP:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE SPName
@Id nvarchar(50)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT * FROM TableName
WHERE ColumnName = @Id 
END
GO
```

Code:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(spName, connection) { CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure })
{
    command.parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(*paramaeter name*, sqlDbType.nvarchar){ Value = "SomeValue"};
}
```

Comment: so you dont want to pass parameter or you dont know parameter name ?

Comment: If I understand right, you want to call an sp that has a parameter call @Id say, with a parameter called @somethingelse?  I don't think that's possible, but I'm also struggling to understand why you would want to - what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to write a generic method in which I pass params object[] and loop through them to fill the parameter collection to pass to the SP. My point is I do not want to be obliged to pass the param name as well.

Comment: @ahmadn. the reason I marked this question as a duplicate is because the linked-to question is (of course) the same but more importantly the top answer gives you what you need.

Comment: @AndrasZoltan The link you provided contains the solution I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple fact - you ultimately have to use the correct parameter name when calling a stored procedure because SQL server binds parameters by name (even when you use EXEC to call an SP without using named parameters, the parser binds them by name from left to right).

So if you want to use a different name you will need to introduce an intermediate layer between your `SqlCommand` and the target SP.

But if you just want to not care about the name and have it automatically discovered - then you can use the technique mentioned by [Conrad Frix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/119477/conrad-frix) in his accepted answer on [SQL Server & .net support calling a stored procedure with param's values wihout providing param's names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6463010/sql-server-net-support-calling-a-stored-procedure-with-params-values-wihout) - which is why I've marked as a duplicate, because it is ultimately what you want to do, even if the reasons are different.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a generic style function, without needing an extra round-trip, and you're happy to use reflection you could use something like this.

```
// Return an array of SqlParameter's by using reflection on ParamObject
private static SqlParameter[] GetParametersFromObject( object ParamObject )
{

    var Params = new List<SqlParameter>();

    foreach( var PropInfo in ParamObject.GetType().GetProperties() )
    {
        Params.Add( new SqlParameter( PropInfo.Name, PropInfo.GetValue( ParamObject, null ) ) );
    }

    return Params.ToArray();

}

public static void ExecuteSP( SqlConnection Connection, string SPName, object ParamObject )
{

    using( var Command = new SqlCommand() )
    {

        Command.Connection = Connection;
        Command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        Command.CommandText = SPName;

        Command.Parameters.AddRange( GetParametersFromObject( ParamObject ) );

        // Command.ExecuteReader()...

    }

}
```

This uses reflection to get the property names and values out of the anonymous object to populate the SqlCommand. This can be used as such;

```
ExecuteSP( Conn, "GetStuff", new { Id = 7, Name = "Test" } );
```

This way ExecuteSP is 'generic' and you pick the parameter names and values when you call ExecuteSP.

Answer (score 1):

For SqlServer there is a [DeriveParameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters) method that takes a command object and queries the database for the parameters (names and types) of the requested stored procedure.

You can then iterate over them and supply values.

Note: this means an extra trip to the database, so if you need this often, you might want to cache the results.

Answer (score 0):

The method below allows you to write generic code for calling stored procedures, but also gives you the flexibility to perform specific actions for each different stored procedure

```
public delegate void SqlCOmmandDelegate(SqlCommand command);

public class Dal
{
    public void ExecuteStoredProcedure(string procedureName, 
        SqlCommandDelgate commandDelegate)
    {
        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
        {
            connection.ConnectionString = GetConnectionString();
            using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
            {
                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                command.CommandText = procedureName;
                connection.Open();
                commandDelegate(command);
            }
        }
    }
}

class UsesDal
{
    public CallFirstProcedure(int value)
    {
        string userName;

        ExecuteStoredProcedure("FIRST_PROCEDURE",
            delegate(SqlCommand command)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("UserID", value);
                command.ExecuteReader();

                //Do stuff with results e.g.
                username = command.Parameters.Parameters["UserName"].ToString();
            }
    }

    public CallOtherProcedure(string value)
    {
        int id;
        ExecuteStoredProcedure("OTHER_PROCEDURE",
            delegate(SqlCommand command)
            {
                command.Parameters.Add("ParameterName", value);
                id = command.ExecuteScalar();
            }
    }
}
```